# Constant term of a power modulo a polynomial

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, finite-fields

I'm interested in the constant term of $$(x+k)^m \in F_p[x]$$
modulo a polynomial $q(x)$ over the field $F_p$. The polynomial $q(x)$ is relatively simple in practice, take $q(x) = x^6 -2x^3+3$, for an example. The power, $m$ is large relative to the degree.

Writing out the equation and expanding gives a messy, large, but solvable recurrence in the degree of the $q(x)$.

I'm wondering if anyone has done this sort of calculation before or has an easier method? It seems like the sort of problem that would occur in a combinatorics text somewhere.

Comment: Have you tried the Euclidean algorithm?

Comment: Yes, that gives the recurrence. I want to find an explicit formula for all $m,k$.

Comment: Perhaps better not to have two meanings for $p$.

Comment: This is a solution of a linear recurrence with characteristic polynomial $q$, like Fibonacci sequence. It has a so-so explicit form via the roots of $q$.

Comment: You can compute $(x+k)^m \bmod q(x)$ efficiently using binary exponentiation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: To elaborate on Fedor Petrov's comment, if $q(x-k)=\sum_{i=0}^{d} a_i x^i$ then $b_m:=(x+k)^m \bmod q(x)$ satisfies the recurrence $\sum_{i=0}^{d} a_i b_{m+i} = 0$.

Comment: Solving the recurrence the standard way, you can re-write it as the constant term of $(k+\alpha)^m$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $q(x)$. But that doesn't help get an explicit answer in terms of $m$ and $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of $q(x)$ over $F_p$, and $I$ be the identity matrix of the same size. Then the constant term of $(x+k)^m\bmod q(x)$ can be explicitly expressed as
$$u (C+kI)^m u^T,$$
where $u:=(1,0,0,\dots,0)$.

In practice this formula enables immediate application of [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Matrices). Alternatively, computation can be done using [Fiduccia algorithm](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/0214007) or [similar](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.06376) [methods](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.08822).